# UICollectionViewCell Content Issues on Scroll

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm implementing cell content inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath` just adding `UIImageView` and drawing and centering image inside and it looks good until i scroll collection view!!! See images!!!

```
// ...........cell content setup

            switch indexPath.row {

            case 0:
                cell.alpha = 0.0
            case 1:
                // ...........drawing singular on cell content view

                var cellImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height))
                cellImageView.image = MyStyles.imageOfSingular(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50.5, 50.5))
                cellImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
                cell.backgroundView = cellImageView

                // ...........
```

[image: Befor i scroll collection]
[image: After scrolling there is an image appearing on cell indexPath 3]
You can see that After scrolling there is an image appearing on cell indexPath 3 i don't need it there!!!
I don't know how to deal with! SOS

The final picture looks like this

[image: final pic]

But after scrolling it looks like this

[image]
I deal with text duplicate this way:

```
// ...........title setup and check if cellTitle exists to avoid title overlaping

        let cellTitle = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height))

        for cellTitle in cell.contentView.subviews {

            if (cellTitle.isKindOfClass(UILabel)) {

                cellTitle.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
```

But don't know what to do with images!

Comment: Do you understand that cells are reused when you scroll? Do a search on cell reuse, and you should find some answers.

Comment: What is the purpose of the switch? Why don't you just set the image?

Comment: Yes, i understand about cell reuse!!!

Comment: The purpose of switch is because i want images only in specific cell only!

Comment: Other cell will have text

Answer (score 0):

I Just figured it out!!! Label is a subview of contentView but not backgroundView!!! So instead `cell.contentView.subviews` i just loop in `cell.subviews` and my images just staring where they are and not populating other cells on scrolling because of reusable cell!

```
for cellImageView in cell.subviews {

            if (cellImageView.isKindOfClass(UIImageView)) {

                cellImageView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
```